# PHP Curl connect to page an wait for redirect

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to scrape data from  a page an trying to use CURL in PHP.

The problem is that the site sometimes is under heavy load and gives me a meassage of "Just a moment...Your request is being processed..." and has a meta refresh every 5 seconds until the server is available. this could be multiple refreshes.

I have tried  adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

this does not help since  it refreshes multiple times.

is there any way to get it to wait until there is no more refresh or confirm it has reached the next page somehow?

the curl script is curently

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

any help is appreciated. 
if this cant be done with curl would you suggest another method?

Comment: Please post the meta refresh.

Comment: This can only be done by repeating the request. Make sure the service you're connecting to agrees to your repeated requests. You are contributing to the heavy load after all

Comment: yes they allow scraping.

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5">

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<?php
    $data= "" ;
    $retries = 0;
    while( preg_match('/<meta http-equiv="refresh"/im', $data) or  $retries < 5){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if(!preg_match('/<meta http-equiv="refresh"/im', $data))
        {
            break;
        }
        $retries++;
        sleep(2);
    }
?>
```

---

The above will try to parse the `html` for 5 times and wait **2** seconds between retries, util the `html` doesn't contain `<meta http-equiv="refresh`

Comment: this just resubmits request. adding to the server load. i want it to stay on the single connection.